# In XBMC, "OK", "Vol +/-" and "Back" buttons not working

Tags: 12.04, remote, xbmc, lirc

I have an [Asus S1-AT5NM10E](http://www.asus.com/Barebone_PCs/S1AT5NM10E/) HTPC which has an integrated IR receiver. On Ubuntu 12.04, I have installed XBMC, but when I press "OK", "Vol +/-" or "Back" on my MCE remote (in fact, a Logitech Harmony 300i configured to emulate an MCE remote), XBMC doesn't seem to detect the signals. However, arrow buttons do work well.

I know that the faulty buttons are detected by the computer because, when I run `cat /dev/lirc0`, a bunch of weird characters are displayed each time I press one of them. The IR receiver is also able to detect a completely different remote (TV) because another family of characters were displayed.

I have installed `lirc` (`sudo apt-get install lirc`) to see the output of `irw`. Unfortunately, `irw` didn't output anything.

Thanks to `ir-keytable`, I could determinate the integrated IR receiver is from Nuvoton:

```
$ ir-keytable 
Found /sys/class/rc/rc0/ (/dev/input/event4) with:
        Driver nuvoton-cir, table rc-rc6-mce
        Supported protocols: NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY LIRC other 
        Enabled protocols: LIRC 
        Extra capabilities: <access denied>
```

Why are some buttons not working? How can I make them work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it is a problem of mapping, or something.

Just run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lirc`, and in the first screen (*Remote control configuration:*), select *Windows Media Center Transceivers/Remotes (all)*.
In the second screen (*IR transmitter, if present:*), you can select *None*.

Now, `irw` can output text:

```
$ sudo irw
000000037ff07be1 00 KEY_UP mceusb
000000037ff07be1 01 KEY_UP mceusb
000000037ff07bdf 00 KEY_LEFT mceusb
000000037ff07bdf 01 KEY_LEFT mceusb
000000037ff07bde 00 KEY_RIGHT mceusb
000000037ff07bde 01 KEY_RIGHT mceusb
000000037ff07be0 00 KEY_DOWN mceusb
000000037ff07be0 01 KEY_DOWN mceusb
000000037ff07bdd 00 KEY_OK mceusb
000000037ff07bdd 01 KEY_OK mceusb
000000037ff07bdc 00 KEY_BACK mceusb
000000037ff07bdc 01 KEY_BACK mceusb
```

And, every buttons in XBMC are detected.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like much of ir-related stuff was moved into the kernel, and lirc used to complicate things. But, I just tried with a clean 14.04.01 and this answer works. Make sure you restart xbmc/kodi after installing lirc.

Comment: also, if you have not got lirc installed, and a simple apt-get install lirc solved this for me. thanks